# A riddle to make a channel queasy

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, computer-puzzle

An accidental discovery of mine, this groan-worthy riddle is answerable *with a single character* when posted in a [Slack](https://slack.com/about) channel:

> What governs the level of disease?

As this is my first riddle here I'm wary of making it too obscure, so here are a few hints:

Hint 1:

> The wordplay here might make you seasick.

Hint 2:

> Actually, only the person who posts the riddle can supply the one-character answer!

Hint 3:

> If this is too all too backwards, let me know and I'll edit it.

Hint 4 (the clincher?) :

> Since Deusovi is *so close* I'll add that the character you're looking for shows up on no keyboard. In fact it's *invisible*. The final result requires no creative reading, although is, as  PuzzledPig notes, best read aloud.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE you can get a badge by taking a tour here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour! :D

Comment: Sadly, Slack seem to have disallowed the quirk that makes this riddle answerable. I wonder if any other delivery-method-dependent jokes have been lost to the mists of time in a similar manner. Rest in peace, idiotic riddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it the

> [Right-to-left mark?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)

Most of the credit goes to Deusovi for the explanation.  Based on hint 2, the riddle will look like

> What governs the level of disease? [RTL_MARK] ‮(edited)

because

> after the original poster edits their comment with the rtl mark, the text *(edited)* will be reversed.  Fortunately, this doesn't mess with the parentheses.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is

> the letter S, posted in an edited comment

because

> when you read "s (edited)" backwards, it becomes "detides", and *the tides* govern the level of *the seas*.

Comment: I still think this is a really smooth answer

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

> the letter "e"?

As that could lead to:

> a (groan-worthy) pun regarding disease/di seas ("the seas," if said somewhat casually)

And it works with most of the hints:

1:

> The seas, in making you seasick, are governing the level of disease

2:

> In Slack, only the person who posts a comment can then edit it (in this case, by putting a space between diseas and e)

3:

> This is the one I'm not sure about.  Perhaps because e is the last letter of the word you'd have to edit in Slack?